# Unexpected \obeylines behavior in an environment

Tags: environments, everypar

I am puzzled by the fact that when `\obeylines` is placed within a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair *inside an environment,* an argument to a macro in that environment seems still to be under the influence of the `\obeylines` command -- I'm likely forgetting something embarrassingly basic.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\tabtox
\newtoks\msctox

\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \def\tst#1 #2 #3~{%
        \global\tabtox=\expandafter{\the\tabtox
            \textbf{#3,} #1\ #2
            \par
        }~% we want a `\par`
    }%
}%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{startit}{}{%
    \begingroup
        \obeylines
        \offinterlineskip
        \everypar={\tst}
}{%
    \the\msctox\par
    \the\tabtox
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\finishthis}{+m}{%
    \endgroup
    \msctox={#1}
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

The argument to \string\finishthis\ seems still to\\be under the influence of \string\obeylines:

\begin{startit}
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f
4 g h
\finishthis{a
b
c
f}
\end{startit}

\bigskip

This works as expected:

\tabtox={}%
\begingroup
\obeylines
\offinterlineskip
\everypar={\tst}
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f
4 g h
\endgroup
\msctox={a
b
c
f}

\the\msctox\par
\the\tabtox
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\endit`(a really bad name:-)  `\begin{it}hmmm\end{it}`  grabs its argument before `\endgroup` is seen so all the line ends are actve tokens

Comment: Yes, execrable name. Changed. The problem remains, however. Was going to rename to `\finishit` but thought better of that...

Comment: `\def\foo{\endgroup\foob}\def\foob#1{stuff...#1..}` so argument grabbed after the group ends

Comment: Ah. When `\finishthis` is encountered and expanded, it does so while `\obeylines` is active, so any arguments would be expanded under the same conditions. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: yes see `\foo`  above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to grab the argument after the group ends so it gets normal catcode 5 line ends:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtoks\tabtox
\newtoks\msctox

\begingroup
    \lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{%
\endgroup
    \def\tst#1 #2 #3~{%
        \global\tabtox=\expandafter{\the\tabtox
            \textbf{#3,} #1\ #2%%%%%%%%%%
            \par
        }~% we want a `\par`
    }%
}%

\NewDocumentEnvironment{startit}{}{%
    \begingroup
        \obeylines
        \offinterlineskip
        \everypar={\tst}%%%%%%%%%%
}{%
    \the\msctox\par
    \the\tabtox
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\finishthis}{}{%
    \endgroup
    \finishthisinternal
}
\def\finishthisinternal#1{%
    \msctox={#1}%%%%%%%%%%
}

%% |=====8><-----| %%

\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

This works as expected:

\begin{startit}
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f
4 g h
\finishthis{a
b
c
f}
\end{startit}

\bigskip

This works as expected:

\tabtox={}%
\begingroup
\obeylines
\offinterlineskip
\everypar={\tst}
1 a b
2 c d
3 e f
4 g h
\endgroup
\msctox={a
b
c
f}

\the\msctox\par
\the\tabtox
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent. And I learned something. A good day.